# Handling Exception: code doesn't terminate

Tags: java, loops, exception

I am actually doing an exception handling for reading inputs from a file with good and bad inputs.

This is the Bank.java, which reads a file through the readFile() and uses the read() to read each account and add them to the bank list.

```
/**
      Read a file with account numbers and balances and adds the accounts
      to the bank.
      @param filename the name of the file
   */
   public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
   {
       File inFile = new File(fileName);
       try(Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile)){
          read(in);
      };

   }

    /**
      Read a file with account numbers and balances and adds the accounts
      to the bank.
      @param in the scanner for reading the input
    */
   private void read(Scanner in)
   {
       while (in.hasNext()){
           BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
           account.read(in);
           addAccount(account);
       }
   }
```

BankAccount.java:

```
   /**
      Reads an account number and balance.
      @param in the scanner

   */
   public void read(Scanner in)
   {

       try{
           accountNumber = in.nextInt();
       } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
           accountNumber = 0;
       }

       try{
           balance = in.nextDouble();
       } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
           balance = 0;
       }
   }
```

This the file that I read data from:

```
1 5000
2 300
3 4500
4 10000
5 3500
6 5652s
7 12000
8 3498
9 34897
10 3451
```

It has a letter in the 6th bankAccount, so that should be handled, and and the accountNumber = 0 and the balance. But what is actually happening when debugging, it reads everything correctly till the 6th account, making the account and balance 0, however, when it continues reading, it makes all the next accountNumbers and balances as 0 and continues forever!

Note: Everything goes right when I try it with the right input file

What is the problem?

This is the main:

```
public class BankReader
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      boolean done = false;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (!done)
      {
         System.out.print("Filename: ");
         String filename = in.next();

         try
         {
            Bank bank = new Bank();
            bank.readFile(filename);
            BankAccount highest = bank.getHighestBalance();
            System.out.println("Highest balance account:");
            System.out.println(highest.getAccountNumber()
                  + " " + highest.getBalance());
            done = true;
         }   
         catch (IOException e)
         {   
            System.out.println(e);
         }

      }//while
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `in.next()` after `accountNumber = 0;`.

`nextInt` doesn't skip word if it is not `int` so you try to parse it again and again.